# How to keep the WiFly shield connected for sending or receiving buffer (Arduino, client side)

Tags: c++, client, wifi, arduino

How do I keep [WiFly](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9367) shield connected for sending or receiving from a buffer?

I need to keep it in the connected state with the server and wait for the server sending data more than once.

I had tested, but saw that it can only receive once from the server, and then it can not receive anymore, unless I close the connection and re-connect again. But I don't want to re-connect!

Code:

```
loop{
    Package sendbuf;  //Package is a structure for converting buffer to Package struct
    sendbuf.header = 0xaa;
    if (client.connect())
        logon(sendbuf,client); //Send message to server; request log in.

    while (client.connected()) {
        //=====================================//
        //      while receive buffer           //
        //=====================================//

        if (client.available()) {
            unsigned char rxBuffer[256] = {};
            delay(10);

            //=======Receive buffer process=======
            int index=-1;
            do{
                index++;
                rxBuffer[index] = client.read();

                if (rxBuffer[index] == 0xff)
                {
                  index--;
                }
            } while (client.available());

            Package* buf = (Package*)rxBuffer;
            int result = readBufferfromServer(buf);

            if (result == 2)  //result:2 mean log in is a success!
            {
                security(sendbuf, client); //Send security message to the server.
            }
            else
                if (result == 1)  //result:1 mean security checking is a success!
                {
                    //Do something
                }

        }// end of client avaliable
    }
```

Comment: It's really hard to help you debug code we cannot see.

Comment: Are you connecting to a web-server? In that case it's the default behavior of the server, to disconnect after each request.

Comment: to Joachim Pileborg: but the server I create dose not disconnect after request,because I want client stay online and wait command form server all the time.